# Microsoft Exchange: How To Resolve A Distinguished Name

Tags: c#, active-directory, exchange-server, distinguishedname

How can i resolve this:

```
/O=CHEESE/OU=FIRST ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=LHALA1
```

to an email address? Do i have to use Exchange Web Services?

Comment: I too am curious about this!

Comment: That is a perfectly valid EX-type address. Do you want to resolve it to an SMTP address? Resolve using what API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is the legacyExchangeDN Attribute.

Try something like this:

```
string dn = "/O=CHEESE/OU=FIRST ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP/" +
        "CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=LHALA1";
string MailAddress=string.Empty;
string user = string.Empty;

using (DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher())
{
    ds.Filter = string.Format("(&(ObjectClass=User)(legacyExchangeDN={0}))", 
            dn);
    SearchResultCollection src = ds.FindAll();
    if (src.Count > 1)
    {
        //Oops too many!
    }
    else
    {
        user = src[0].Properties["samAccountName"][0].ToString();
        MailAddress = src[0].Properties["Mail"][0].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can do an LDAP search of the directory you can retrieve the entry for that user and then the default email address will be in the mail: attribute

If it is a mailbox-enabled Exchange user there will also be addresses in the proxyAddresses: attribute, of a contact or a non-mailbox mail-enabled user there will be remote addresses in the targetAddress: attribute